# low resolution canadian province boundaries in latitude longitude

Tags: coordinates, shapefile

I'm looking for boundaries in lat/lon for Canadian provinces with less than a hundred or so coordinates for each state.

Similar one for US: econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml

I could get the full boundaries (thousands of coordinates for each), but I'm not sure how to scale it down to a hundred or so coordinates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm

The Digital files were way bigger than I needed, but MySQL handles 100k points per province no problem. The Digital files don't have extreme detail as the cartographic maps. The shapefile for the entire country was only 2MB.